local csv file Module parse failed: Unexpected token
./app/dashboard/datalake/data.csv
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (2:5)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| Name,Age,Occupation

John Doe,30,Web Developer
| Marcus Johnson,45,Software Engineer
| Emily Davis,40,CEO

